# Why is incorrect Travel Time: < 1 minute being reported by ArcGIS Network Analyst Find Route?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst, arcgis-10.4

I have configured a network dataset using ArcGIS 10.4.1 for Desktop and am testing it using the Find Route tool.  Results are as expected except that on the Directions tab the Travel Time is always being reported as **`Travel Time: < 1 minute`**.

The example below travels along a single poly line which Identify reports has LENGTH = 3061.1 (metres), SPEED = 50 (kmh) and Minutes = 3.67479.  Consequently, I would expect that Travel Time reported would be 3.67479 minutes.

[image]

The network dataset properties which I think are relevant are as below and the network dataset has been re-built and ArcMap re-started since I calculated the Minutes field.

[image]

[image]

Is there an obvious setting/step that I am likely to be missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just re-created the network dataset with the Minutes field already in place.

By doing this it was recognized straight away and I had no need to add an Attribute on the Network Dataset Properties.

Previously, I had added and calculated it after creating the network dataset, and then added a Time descriptor and set it to the Minutes field.

For the same test I got an expected result below.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is that you probably did not tell ArcGIS to actually use the `Minutes` field you calculated.

In the second screenshot (for "Network Dataset Properties" dialog), there are **two** `Cost` fields, `Length` and `Time`.

1. I guess the `Length` is mapped to `Shape_Length` automatically. And the `Time` field needs to be mapped to your calculated attribute `Minutes`.
2. It is possible that you need to choose `Time` as the default proxy for computing travel cost. Comparing the example from ESRI for [Modifying network attributes](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/network-analyst/editing-network-datasets-modifying-network-attributes.htm), their example also have two cost fields (called `Meters` and `Minutes`), but they had `Minutes` as the default. From your screenshot, it seems you had `Length` as the default. I am not sure how ArcGIS choose/combine different cost factors or whether ArcGIS itself is computing time based on travel speed, but the two cost factors are different, and which one to use may need to be specified somehow.

Comment: I think it is something like this because I just created a new network dataset from the same polyline feature class and, because I already had the Minutes field in place, it picked it up and worked fine.  I'll add an answer to that effect in a moment.  Thanks for looking at it.  I favour your answer for the bounty at this point.

Answer (score 1):

See [How To: Display hours, minutes, and seconds in the Network Analyst Directions window](http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000011511). You can change config files for both arcgis desktop NA and arcgis for server NA.

I faced same problem two years ago. We had  a mobile project and want to use network analysis in mobile. For this purpose we used result of arcgis network analyst in json. When you publish network dataset in arcgis for server you can use the result of network analysis in json. Then the correct time will be show for users

Comment: This does not sound like the same problem but I tested it anyway.  When I replaced the `directions.xml` and `resources.xml` in  `C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.4\NetworkAnalyst\Directions` with those from http://downloads2.esri.com/support/TechArticles/Article40006.zip it caused the add stop (interactive) step to throw a Serious Application Error.  Changing back to the originals caused the add stops to work again so I suspect that they are not designed to work with 10.4.1.

Comment: The structure of xml is varied in different arcgis versions. You should customize xml files of arcgis 10.4.